# How to define a class or import one in a Scrapbook?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, import, code-snippets

I need to test some code on the fly using the Eclipse Scrapbook. Is this even the best way to do it? I don't come from a Java background. Anyways, its frustrating me because I'm trying to define a simple class in Java:

```
public class RegistrationResponse {
    public String message;
    public Boolean success;
}
```

I want to use this class in my Scrapbook. So here's my project structure:

```
src
 |-(default package)
 |        |- RegistrationResponse.java
 |- Scrapbook.jpage
```

I went into my Scrapbook, and added the RegistrationResponse type from the Java Snippet Imports window. Then, when I run my code, it tells me this:

> The import RegistrationResponse cannot be resolved

You gotta be kidding me. How do I do this? Anyways, I noticed I wasn't able to add the default package in my snippet imports. Is that why its failing? Is it supposed to be added by default or no?

Comment: Do not put classes into Default package. put it into a subpackage.

Comment: @Jens Thanks, that worked. I put it in a sub-package and then I was able to import that sub-package. Man, it takes so long to get work done in Java using this Scrapbook style of programming. Is there no way for it to auto-resolve dependencies faster based on the project you're working on? Or do you literally have to import each type and each package you use? That is so demanding and time consuming...

Comment: Which IDE do you use? If you are using eclipse, you con use shift+ctrl+o to Import all referenced classes

Comment: Excellent. That worked. Also, one last quick question for you (off topic, sorry). Does Eclipse support alt selection?

Comment: What do you mean with alt selection?

Comment: @Jens So, in Visual Studio, or even Notepad++, you can hold alt down while selecting multiple lines of text (while also holding down the left mouse button), and this allows you to edit multiple lines at once. For example, you select 5 lines of text at a certain column, and start typing "hello", and it shows up on all 5 lines at whatever column has the focus.

Comment: I do not know about such Feature in eclipse

Comment: @Jens When you start using it, it becomes a necessity. Check it out sometime :)

Comment: @Jens You should post this as an answer so I can award the answer to you!

Comment: i have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not put classes into Default package. put it into a subpackage.

If you are using eclipse, you con use shift+ctrl+o to Import all referenced classes